# How to create a circle with text coming out of it like rays

Tags: html, css, geometry

I'd like to have a circle, with rays coming out of it... Around 24 of them. With each ray being a rectangle with a word in it. So it's basically a menu in a website, but instead of being in a column on the side of the page, here it's around a circle. Each rectangle is evenly separated from the others of course, forming something that looks like a sun.

Can anyone show me how I can do that with HTML/CSS? Javascript and JQuery can be used too if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PaKu/)?

In the fiddle I use a javascript loop to set all the angles, but it could also be static css if you knew ahead of time how many rays there would be:

```
.ray {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    transform-origin: 0px 50%;
}

#ray1 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#ray2 {
    transform: rotate(72deg);
}
...
```

(naturally for real-world code you'd want to use the -webkit, etc prefixes for the transform properties; another nicety of using jquery is that it deals with that automatically)